# Prove that if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f'(a)=0$ then $f''(x)=0$ for some $x \in (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:(c,d) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is twice differentiable and $c<a<b<d$.
>  Prove that if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f'(a)=0$ then $f''(x)=0$ for some $x \in (a,b)$

I know that function is convex / concave when $f''(x)\ge/\le0$. However I think it will not help me in this task.
 Can you help me with it?

Comment: Hint: use Rolle's theorem once on $f$, then again on $f'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVT implies $f’(c)=0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. The MVT again implies $f’’(d)=0$ for some $d\in(a,c)$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much